# GmailThread.reply does not have original message in body

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am replying to an email using [GmailThread.reply(body)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message.html#reply(String))
But the problem is that unlike replying using gmail app on web or android, the replies do not have a copy of original message.
Here is my code:

```
function testreply() {
 var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();  
  Logger.log(threads[0].getFirstMessageSubject());
  threads[0].reply("test reply");
}
```

My question is that is this the expect behaviour?
Is it possible to include the original message in the reply(just as gmail web which adds special formatting to the original message in reply)?

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question on [Gmail Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/L6zEEr9akCA). According to this, you need to construct the entire message body to pass to the Reply method. You can get the body and headers from the original message to construct the final form.

Also try to check [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/gmail/composing-and-sending-messages/4ramSYSN_go) for more information.

Comment: How do we construct the entire message body IN GOOGLE APPS SCRIPT that looks exactly like the one in gmail? The links don't hint about that anywhere